# Plot a histogram and having problem with relative frequency

Tags: r

I was trying to find the relative frequency of vector a, but the y-axis is showing numbers greater than 1. The relative frequency should be less than or equal to 1, right? Below is my code.

```
a = vector()
for (i in 1:100){
          flips <- rbinom(4,3,0.5)
          X <- mean(flips)
          a <- append(a, X)
    }
mean(a)
sd(a)
hist(a,freq=FALSE,main="100 Binomial Random Variables", xlab="Number of Successes",ylab="Relative Frequency", col="lightblue")
```

Comment: From the R console, type `help(hist)` and scroll down to the `Details` section. Your result will depend on a few things about your data that we can't see from here. Relative Frequency isn't automatically the answer given; the `Value` section explains why.

Comment: I just edited my post, now it shows all the code@Jason

Comment: It's not obvious to a beginner, but this sentence `If all(diff(breaks) == 1), they are the relative frequencies...` means that you only get relative frequencies if the step size between breaks is exactly 1. Our histogram height results will differ (because of the random number generator), but the breaks are spaced 0.5 apart. In this case, you have the density, not the relative frequency. The sum of the heights times widths = 1. The narrower the bar, the higher it's allowed to be, and 1 is the limit of the area, not height.

Comment: To address the question in your first sentence, here's a clues: print the histogram numbers, as well as plotting them, like so: `h1 <- hist(a, ...)` followed by simply typing `h1` on the next line. Note the `$counts` component. That should get you closer.